# JQuery Reload/refresh page while site browse on mobile while locked

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to refresh the page after 5 seconds while mobile is locked.

so that page will refresh automatically

Answer (score 0):

you can do that with just plain javascript try this bro

```
function refresh(){
    window.location = window.location.href;
}
setInterval('refresh()', 5000);
```

Comment: it is working in active browser in mobile. but not working while locked or background

Answer (score 0):

can refresh page without Js:
refresh page every 10 sec

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10" >
```

Comment: it is working in active browser in mobile. but not working while locked or background

Comment: You may must work with service worker. see more https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/service-workers-in-javascript/